# jQuery sliding upon fadeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking at the jQuery API, and they have this example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>fadeOut demo</title>
  <style>
  span {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  span.hilite {
    background: yellow;
  }
  div {
    display: inline;
    color: red;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Find the modifiers - <div></div></h3>
<p>
  If you <span>really</span> want to go outside
  <span>in the cold</span> then make sure to wear
  your <span>warm</span> jacket given to you by
  your <span>favorite</span> teacher.
</p>

<script>
$( "span" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).fadeOut( 1000, function() {
    $( "div" ).text( "'" + $( this ).text() + "' has faded!" );
    $( this ).remove();
  });
});
$( "span" ).hover(function() {
  $( this ).addClass( "hilite" );
}, function() {
  $( this ).removeClass( "hilite" );
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is similar to my code.  Is there a way to make the remaining paragraph slide to the left when the phrase is removed, to make that transition smoother?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to animate the p tag. It's the parent of what you have clicked on, so something like this should work...

```
$( this ).remove().parent('p').animate({
    'margin-left' : '-500px'
}, 300);
```